# Nvim plug in aerial not loaded

Tags: neovim-plugin

Hi there I just start using Neovim it's fantastic so far. I chose Nvchad for the beginning and tried to add some custom plugins such as aerial.nvim for the tag bars. But it doesn't work. If you have any good ideas to solve it, very thank you

```
{
  'stevearc/aerial.nvim',
  -- Optional dependencies
  dependencies = {
     "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
     "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons"
  },
  opts = function()
    require("aerial").setup({
      -- optionally use on_attach to set keymaps when aerial has attached to a buffer
      on_attach = function(bufnr)
      -- Jump forwards/backwards with '{' and '}'
      vim.keymap.set("n", "{", "<cmd>AerialPrev<CR>", { buffer = bufnr })
      vim.keymap.set("n", "}", "<cmd>AerialNext<CR>", { buffer = bufnr })
      end,
    })
    -- You probably also want to set a keymap to toggle aerial
    vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>tb", "<cmd>AerialToggle!<CR>")
    end,
  }
}

return plugins
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQUgN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53wgf.jpg)

I tried some bunch of different style of function method such as config = function
etc.
but Faild to use it